# FileNameEditor не работает в Windows7

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net

1. Создаю свой наследник от `FileNameEditor` (чтобы задать расширение)
2. Создаю класс, редактирование которого предполагается через `PropertyGrid`
3. Я использую `PropertyGrid` из `DevExpress 7.3.5`, а не стандартный
4. Свойство класса, которое надо редактировать как путь, помечаю атрибутом `[Editor(typeof(FilterPathEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]`. `FilterPathEditor` - это мой наследник `FileNameEditor`.
5. В Windows XP всё OK, в Windows7 диалог открывается, но по нажатию на кнопку выбора файла поле не заполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, это известный [баг DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B133063.aspx).

Но от этого не легче, так как в более новой версии, в которой он должен быть исправлен, есть не менее критичный для проекта баг.